# cannot create page method "GetCompletionList" because no CodeBehind or CodeFile file was found! Ajax Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am am in need of help with regards to the following error that I am getting when clicking on "Add AutoComplete page method" on a textbox control in an aspx page: "Cannot create page method "GetCompletionList" because no CodeBehind or CodeFile file was found!". This is related to adding an Ajax control to a webpage object such as a textbox.

I have successfully added the Ajax Control Toolkit to my website toolbox in Visual Studio 2012. I have followed the following tutorial http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoC… and get the error when I get to step 4.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Here is an extract of my code thus far:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="rightContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  


<td class="tdLeftSide">Manufacturer:</td>
                <td class="tdRightSide" style="width: 264px">
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtManufacturer" runat="server" CssClass="txtFormatting"></asp:TextBox></td>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtManufacturer" runat="server" CssClass="txtFormatting"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtManufacturer_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="" TargetControlID="txtManufacturer" UseContextKey="True">
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                </td>
```

Comment: What kind of item did you add to your project to get the initial page ,to which you are adding markup to? Is it a `WebForm` or something else?

Comment: It is a WebForm though the Ajax control involved is called an AutoCompleteExtender.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code manually into the code-behind and wiring up the `ServiceMethod` attribute on the extender control yourself?

Comment: I have tried manually inserting the code into the code-behind though I am not sure how to wire up the ServiceMethod on the extender control. I do not know what it it expects - I will do a bit more research in this regard. (I would like to keep this control static as shown in the tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually write the code-behind and then apply the method name `GetCompletionList` to the `ServiceMethod` attribute of the extender control, like this:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ID="txtManufacturer_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="" TargetControlID="txtManufacturer" UseContextKey="True">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have been fighting with this Ajax control for quite some time. I implemented your solution and it now works as expected.

Comment: Yes, the AJAX controls can be frustrating, but quite useful once you figure out their quirks. Good luck.